# Unable to get "createAt" from Parse PFObject in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a backend and unable to get the createdAt value from a PFObject in iOS, it works fine for PFUser.

This works fine...

```
NSDate *createdAt = [PFUser currentUser].createdAt;
```

But I can't get a date from this. It returns a null value...

```
NSDate *createdAt = self.loggedInuser.createdAt;
```

"self.loggedInuser" is a PFObject that I can NSlog and get its value.

How can I get the createdAt value for the PFObject? I need it because I want certain things to happen, depending on the objects age.

I can add another column to store date values, but I don't want to since it is already there.

Comment: How did you get `self.loggedInuser`? Just created or queried?

Comment: self.loggedInuser is a PFObject that has been queried from Parse. (I  am in a testing/building phase, and self.loggedInuser is essentially related to the PFUser, but holds all the relevant data that is searched against. I am reserving the PFUser for account info, that is never to be passed or searched against by other users.)

Comment: Why is it that enlightenment comes after posting and not in the 3 hours before? Figured it out... I was calling the NSLog on self.loggedInuser BEFORE the query had completed, so createdAt and anything else would have been null. (I was used to accessing info on different controllers after it had been passed, so it was always available).

Answer (score 1):

I was calling the NSLog on self.loggedInuser BEFORE the query had completed, so createdAt and anything else would have been null. (I was used to accessing info on different controllers after it had been passed, so it was always available).